# Issue in working with Oracle validation query

Tags: validation, database-connection, connection-pooling

When we configure JDBC validation query **(select 1 from dual)**, how to ensure that oracle validation query is working in connection pool to resolve close connection problem?

Server starts perfectly after adding validation query in connection properties but we never know whether this query using to check new connection request or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to understand. Could you brief the question.

Comment: When a database server reboots or a network failure occurred, all connections in the database connection pool are broken. It's recommended to use validation query in connection properties of Application Server. My question was about validation query check.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to trace the queries from the database - [SQL_Trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace)

Comment: I have implemented this property but validation query not coming in SQL trace ...why so?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat application server? There are several other parameters you could look at. e.g. testOnBorrow indicates whether objects will be validated before taking from the pool and its default value is false. Also, see the validationInterval parameter (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

Maybe another way for testing is to provide query with errors. In that case errors should be logged in the server log (under debug mode).

Comment: Yes....our application use tomcat application server. I have already added 'testOnBorrow' parameter but validation query not showing in trace session.  Thanks.